# Renaming class - field value in Java

Tags: java, class, uuid

Hey I need change uuid value via `getClass()`, here is my code but I don't know what obiect I must type instead UUID

```
Field uuidField = c.getClass().getDeclaredField("uuid");
uuidField.setAccessible(true);
uuidField.set(UUID, newUuidValue);
```

Comment: Well which instance do you want to set the value on? `c`?

Comment: i need change variable value in `c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the equivalent of

```
c.uuid = newUuidValue;
```

but with reflection, you just want:

```
uuidField.set(c, newUuidValue);
```

The first argument to `set` is a reference to the object whose field you want to modify.

Answer (score -1):

You have to give the instance whose field you want to change which is most likely `c`.